# Find the multiplicative inverse of the nonzero least residues of modulo 13?

Tags: number-theory

I do not know what the question is even asking?? Do I need to find the least residues of mod 13 first, then find the inverse?

Comment: Well, yes, but that's just $\{1,2,\cdots, 12\}$.  After that, just go one by one.  The multiplicative inverse of $1$ is $1$, for instance.

Comment: The "least residue of mod 13" for what number?

Comment: @mk2025: is this what you are looking for https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Table%5BPowerMod%5Bi%2C+-1%2C+13%5D%2C+%7Bi%2C+1%2C+12%7D%5D>

Comment: That's what I was confused about whether or not it's a particular number or a set of numbers that I must find the multiplicative inverse for

Comment: @lulu
So for example, for 1, would the work look like this:                                                   1 (mod 13) = 1*12 ≡ 12 ≡ 1 (mod 13), thus 1^-1 ≡ 12 (mod 13)?

Comment: No.  Given a residue, $r\pmod {13}$, you are looking for a residue $s$ such that $s\times r \equiv 1 \pmod {13}$.  $r=1$ is easy, since of course $1\times 1 =1\equiv 1\pmod {13}$.  $r=2$ is a more interesting place to start.  Can you solve $2s\equiv 1 \pmod {13}$?

Comment: @lulu Ah so 2s ≡ 1 (mod 13) when s= 7 because 2 x 7 = 14 ≡ 1 (mod 13). I see now, thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to specify for what number we need to calculate the "least residue of mod 13".

For example

$$20 \equiv 7 \mod 13$$

then to find the [**inverse**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) of $7 \mod 13$ we can use [**euclidean algorithm**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm), that is

- $13=1\cdot 7+6$
- $7=1\cdot 6+1$

then

$$1=7-6=7-(13-7)=-13+2\cdot 7$$

then $2$ is the inverse of $7 \mod 13$ (easy to guess in that case).

We can repeat the same procedure for all the other residues $\mod 13$.

Answer (score 1):

$2$ is a primitive root modulo $13;$ the consecutive powers of $2$ are $1, 2, 4, 8, 3, 6, 12, 11, 9, 5, 10, 7,$ and  $1\mod 13$. From here you can see that, modulo $13$, the multiplicative inverse of $1$ is $1$, $2$ is $7$, $4$ is $10$, $8$ is $5$, $3$ is $9$, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the extended euclidean algorithm, you can also use Fermat's theorem.

For instance, $1 \equiv 7^{12} = 7 \cdot 7^{11}$. Therefore, the inverse of $7$ mod $13$ is $7^{11}$. It's not so bad as it looks:
$$
7^{11} = 7^{8} \cdot 7^{2} \cdot 7
$$
Now
$$
7^2 = 49 \equiv 10
,\quad
7^4 \equiv 100 \equiv 9
,\quad
7^8 \equiv 81 \equiv 3
$$
Therefore,
$$
7^{11} = 7^{8} \cdot 7^{2} \cdot 7 \equiv 3 \cdot 10 \cdot 7 \equiv 2
$$
This method of finding powers is called [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).